How to get the building instructions for a third party typewriter set?
Does anyone have the manual for this LEGO typewriter clone by chance? I dropped my model and it broke into parts - now I don't know how to put it back together.



I found out that this isn't a knockoff set, this is just the original idea for the typewriter set submitted on Lego Ideas. If you go to the set's Ideas page ( https://ideas.lego.com/projects/075a31a1-7b54-4206-857c-7a9009405cc4 ), there's an Instructions tab but it just redirects you to the instructions for the official released set on Lego.com... Do you remember how you got the instructions? Did the author share a pdf of the original instructions at some point before the official set was released?

@ToomanyBees aw man, I think I got the kit from Temu or eBay of something. Tossed the manual and box after I finished putting it together.

Definitely a knockoff set. Produced by Qizhile, reverse engineered from the pictures of the lego ideas set even before the official set went into production. As such there is very little chance there are digital instructions available.

@Raksha If you want to have instractions, the most you could do is ask the manufacturer (little chance they will even respond) or find other people who bought this exact set and managed to hold on to the building instructions, and hope someone of those will take the time to scan and upload theirs. However, if your goal is just to put the typewriter together again, you'd probably be done sooner by taking the still connected parts and treat them as a 3D puzzle.

@MichaelVerschaeve thank you, I'll try reaching out to them.

The parts in the second photo seem comfortably large and specific, so coupled with the first photo, I'd estimate a restoration to take no more than an hour or maybe two.

@zovits you'd think so but the actual button mechanism is broken too so now they either don't press at all or get jammed
